# Input Parameter Box Date Format

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have data sql statement which compares dates using `some_date_to_compare > date('2011-05-05')` syntax. The date is currently hardcoded in the SQL statement and I would like to change it, to pass the date as a parameter, like this: `some_date_to_compare > date({?date_from})`. The `date_from` is Date type, not Date/Hour.

The problem, however with this is that when I try to run the report Crystal passess the date from the Input Parameter box in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, so for example if I choose `2011-05-05` as a date from the calendar I get `2011-05-05 00:00:00` passed to `date_from` parameter.

Is there any way to have a workaround, or to pass the date in format that I expect (`YYYY-MM-DD`)?

EDIT (some additional informations):

I'm using Informix and the column is of DATE type (not DATETIME - date + time), so it's only date.
Now the part of my sql is as follows:
`date_to_compare between date({?date_from}) AND date({?date_to})`,
so i'm trying to compare value from column in my table against date range.

The problem however is that when Crystal passess the date from Input Parameter Box as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` the result of query validation is: *String to date conversion error: -1218*, and it's because of the time part in the passed date.

Btw, is there any possibility to turn the query validation off by Crystal in the SQL command modification window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a case related with the connection type. Earlier I used simple JDBC connection. Now, when I'm using ODBC connection (Informix driver) the problem with the date format is gone.

Comment: Typical, I hate it when DB drivers cause hassles, exceptionally tricky to spot.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToText()` function can be used to do this.

```
ToText({datefield}, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: But my SQL is under 'Edit Command' window in Database Expert. I think this SQL is what Crystal sends directly do database (just after it replaces any parameters). It seems Crystal doesn't resolve it's own functions there, hence the error: _Routine (totext) can not be resolved: -674_

Comment: @cujo: Ah, could you not make the restriction in the record selection instead?

Comment: @Orbling: I guess you have in mind _Report->Selection Expert_. I'm not quite sure if it's possible in my case. The SQL I have is pretty complicated and I get set of IDs based on the date criteria mentioned above and then get some results based on this IDs and some other criteria. As I see in Selection Expert I can refer to the fields from the SELECT clause.

Comment: @cujo: Just realised you are talking about a Crystal parameter, not sure what version you are using, but on 2008, Date (as opposed to DateTime) is an option for parameters.  Yes, Selection Expert, I believe you can use any field in the data schema.  That will result in a greater load on the report and the SQL server though, as the data will be being cut down locally.

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, it is Input Parameter to the report. Date is choosed from the Crystal datepicker. I'm using Crystal XI

Comment: @cujo: I see from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534498/crystal-reports-2008-problem-with-parameter-type/3546600#3546600), that the earlier versions of Crystal do have a problem with this. In 2008, the parameter type picker looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/99tvu.jpg).

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, it looks exactly the same in XI. However even if I set default date, Crystal keeps asking me to choose this date when I try to modify the SQL command (don't know why). Then comes the problem because it adds extra 'midnight' (00:00:00) information to the date.

Comment: @cujo: Aye, I have experienced the problem and resorted to using the Selection rules to avoid the SQL issue.

Comment: @Orbling: thanks for all your help. I would vote your answer, but still need to gain some reputation to make it happen :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a blank report and Insert the original report as a Subreport. Now in the Main report, create a static parameter of 'Date' type. Create a new Formula called 'Date_conv' and type this:

```
Datetime({?Date_parameter})
```

Then place the subreport on the main report. Right-click the subreport and select Change Subrpeort Links. Select the formula and move it to the Links to area. Next, from the drop-down on the bottom left select the datetime parameter of the subreport.The Report should now prompt for a 'Date' instead of the Date time. Refer the site -
http://scn.sap.com/thread/2085118